# vscode-jest with ts-jest breakpoints in typescript source files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, vscode-debugger

I have a TypeScript project and am using Jest via [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest) for my tests. In VS Code I have the plugin [vscode-jest](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest) installed. Debugging is not quite working as I would like it:

- I can start a debugging session by clicking on the `Debug` CodeLens produced by vscode-jest
- If I put a breakpoint in the **test** code the debugger will pause at the breakpoint as expected
- **But** if I put a breakpoint in the **source** code, the debugger will ignore it

I guess this is because of the way ts-jest works. The breakpoint is probably never found because the tests are being run on the JS files not the TS files.

If I try the same in a JS project that was bootstrapped with Create React App, I can set breakpoints in the source files and the debugger will halt. Which is interesting because these source files are also being compiled by babel...

I wonder if it is possible to tweak my setup so the breakpoints in the source files will be recognised by the debugger.

Posting some files below that are likely to be relevant:

`jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/dist/', '/node_modules/'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
    collectCoverage: false,
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": false
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: Did you make it to work?

Answer (score 1):

uhm, I'm in your situation  but I'm able to set breakpoints both on source code and test code.
Note that even if vscode marks my breakpoints as 'unverified' on source code, it correctly stop when reach them.

I'll pass to you my configuration:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "build",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "scripthost"
        ],
        "traceResolution": false,
        "listEmittedFiles": false,
        "listFiles": false,
        "pretty": true,
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules/**/*.*",
        "build/**/*.*"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "test/**/*.test.ts",
        "demo/**/*.ts"
    ],
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsConfigFile: 'tsconfig.jest.json'
        },
        "__TRANSFORM_HTML__": true
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'ts',
        'js'
    ],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(ts|html)$": "ts-jest",
        "^.+\\.xml$": "<rootDir>/tools/xmlTransformer.js",
    },
    clearMocks: true,
    resetMocks: true,
    restoreMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "**/src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    coverageReporters: [
        'lcov'
    ],
    // "coverageThreshold": {
    //     "global": {
    //         "branches": 80,
    //         "functions": 80,
    //         "lines": 80,
    //         "statements": 80
    //     }
    // },
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    testMatch: [
        '**/test/unit/**/*.test.ts'
    ],
    setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: 'jest-mock-console/dist/setupTestFramework.js'
};
```

---

EDIT: how do you launch jest in debug mode?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Quite likely it was some version of a dependency causing my problem. I've been able to step through everything recently. Your EDIT asks how you would start Jest in debug mode, and my question was about vscode-jest, so I am assuming you want to know how to debug using this plugin. I do this simply by clicking the "Debug" link that will appear over a failing test.

To start a debug session unrelated to vscode-jest you would have to make a launch.json configuration and start your debugging session with that.

Comment: well no, I was asking about launching jest in debug mode just because it was the lonely thing you didn't have specified, so I was thinking about something missing in jest launch params (as, for example, runInBand param)